# Input french accents in Gtk.Entry

Tags: gtk, diacritics

Environment Python 3, Gtk3, Postgresql:
How do I type French accents into a Gtk.Entry box? I can't paste in from  a word-processor, and escapes such as \233 aren't translated into the appropriate character.

Comment: This probably needs more information about what program you're trying to type in. In a normal GtkEntry, pasting characters should work just fine. So should inputting them via your normal input method.

Comment: As I said, it's a Python 3 program using Gtk 3 to maintain my address book. I created the accented word in a LibreOffice document, but neither Ctrl-v nor Shift-Ins would insert it. However, I found a web page containing the word I needed, and Copy/Paste DID work. Is this some sort of coding/UTF-8 problem?

Comment: If you can copy paste from a web page but not a word processor, the problem is not with Gtk but with the word processor.